# Matlab Fetch from MS SQL Server 2008 truncates FILESTREAM/VARBINARY to 32767 bytes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, matlab, sql-server-2008

I'm using Matlab R2014a to access a SQL database.
I uploaded the data to the database using Matlab.
The column is a FILESTREAM of type varbinary(MAX).
When I query the database with a SQL command such as:

SELECT DATALENGTH(imagedata) from imagedata

I get datalengths of 8198400, which is consistent with my image data.

When I query the database with a SQL command such as:

SELECT imagedata from imagedata WHERE imageID<3

I get 32767 bytes of data per image.

SELECT CAST(imagedata AS varbinary(MAX)) from imagedata WHERE imageID<3

...also returns 32767 bytes of data per image.

I suspect this may be related to: [Binary Blob truncated to 8000 bytes - SQL Server 2008 / varbinary(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584170/binary-blob-truncated-to-8000-bytes-sql-server-2008-varbinarymax), but the relationship isn't obvious to me.

One webpage has mentioned that 64-bit Matlab may have issues with ODBC drivers and that switching to JDBC solved the problem, but that isn't a satisfactory solution as I suspect I am either getting the SQL wrong or have some defaults set incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: Well, it turns out that switching to JDBC does solve the problem.  It turns out that it solves the problem a lot faster if you don't misspell the database name, which just gives a rather uninformative login failed error.  I'm still interested in knowing whether this is just a matlab/sql/configuration bug on my end or if there is a real bug in matlab.